# Cordova SQLite plugin error code

Tags: angularjs, sqlite, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

Can somebody please explain me the error message my ionic / cordova app is returning when writing to an already open SQLite DB?

Reading from it works fine, but writing to is not working...

```
[Log] {"db":{"openargs":{"name":"mydb.db","dblocation":"docs"},"dbname":"mydb.db"},"txlock":true,"readOnly":false,"executes":[],"finalized":true} (console-via-logger.js, line 174)
```

This is what SQLite outputs before I run the write transaction:

```
[Log] OPEN database: mydb.db (console-via-logger.js, line 174)
[Log] new transaction is waiting for open operation (console-via-logger.js, line 174)
[Log] DB opened: mydb.db (console-via-logger.js, line 174)
```

That's how I write to it

```
myDB.transaction(function(transaction) {
             var query = "UPDATE Data SET Values='"+dataJSON+"'";
//           console.log(query);
             transaction.executeSql(query,[],
             //On Success
             function(tx, result) {
//               console.log('UPDATE SUCCESSFULLY');
                 deferred.resolve(true);
             },
             //On Error
             function(error){
//               console.log('Backing up data to DB failed');
                 deferred.reject(error);
             });
    });
```

Comment: I have same issue. It seems that the it trying to do transactions before the database is totally open..

Comment: In my case the program already processed a successful read on the DB. Any idea what the error means?

Comment: This read is over the same table you're trying to write?

Comment: Yes, reading it first, doing stuff and then update

Comment: @ElDude: how did u fix that?

Comment: My fix due to timeconstraint : use backend server and ditch SQLite :D

Answer (score 1):

Try to code like this.

```
function(name,email,phoneno){
var deferred = $q.defer();
posts = undefined;
var query = "UPDATE Data SET Name=?, Email=?, Phone=?";
$cordovaSQLite.execute(dbconn, query, [name,email,phoneno])
.then(function(result) {
posts = result;
deferred.resolve(posts);
}, function (error) {
posts = error;
deferred.reject(posts);
});
posts = deferred.promise;
return $q.when(posts);    
}
```